# Google Identity Toolkit GAE user activation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to set up Google Identity Toolkit (GIT) on a test webpage on localhost. I completed all the necessary steps on Google Console and downloaded the Java sample from the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/java), and it's working.

Now what I want to do is disable self-registration (which I couln't disable), create users on GIT, send them an email link activation and set password for first time. I took a look at the [API](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/) provided, but there's no way I can figure out how to use it.

I managed to create users and delete them with `com.google.identitytoolkit` classes like `GitkitClient` and `GitkitUser`, as seen in the example, but I cannot get the email activation and password reset working.

If anybody can point me to some good examples on how to do that, I'll really appreciate it.